# Are there alternatives to Google Cloud Messaging for custom android builds?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We have a custom android build and just figured out the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) maybe an issue on non Google certified builds.

Assuming that is the case, are there any alternatives out there to GCM?

Comment: [UrbanAirship is one such alternative](http://urbanairship.com/)

Comment: UrbanAirship uses GCM under the hood. It just "unifies" notifications for Android, iOS and Blackberry.

Comment: All the alternatives mentioned here simply piggyback on GCM, so they won't be applicable to you. Check out Pushy (https://pushy.me/) for a completely independent push gateway (full disclosure: I founded Pushy)

Comment: Pushy is a standalone push notification gateway, completely independent of GCM. It maintains its own background socket connection, just like GCM, to receive push notifications. The underlying protocol is MQTT, an extremely light-weight pub/sub protocol, utilizing very little network bandwidth and battery. It will be perfect for your use case since it does not depend on Google Play Services. https://pushy.me/

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to implement push notification in android is [parse](http://parse.com)

Just register yourself, create new android app.

Checkout [demo](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) code

Integrate your **ApplicationID** and **Client key**.

Run your app and your are set!

Comment: Parse works without GCM, so I have up voted to counter the down vote you got.

Comment: parse is going to be shut down. any other ?

Comment: The Parse library provides push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) if Google Play Services are available.

Answer (score 4):

You may Try 
[xtify](http://developer.xtify.com/display/support/Xtify+Developer+Documentation+Site)

or

[pushlets](http://www.pushlets.com/)

or

[Urban Airship](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3A+Android%3A+Push)

Comment: xtify appears to use GCM? does it?

Answer (score 3):

[Paho](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) project is an [iot.eclipse.com](http://iot.eclipse.com) project, open-source client for MQTT based server.

You may review android application demo [example](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/sample/).

It will connect to MQTT based sandbox server hosted freely by eclipse to test this application.See this server details [here](http://iot.eclipse.org/sandbox.html)

Comment: Fast and simple! GREAT!

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented Push  Notification [ Using Urban Air Ship]  application in Android, 
 with the help  of the steps shown in the Urbran  Air Ship documentation

http://urbanairship.com/docs/android_client.html,

It works in a nice and fine manner,and also i got notifcation, when my feed is updated. Here's the step what had  done.

Step1: Create a Account in Urban Air Ship,  https://go.urbanairship.com/

Step2: Download android_push.jar from here https://github.com/urbanairship/android-push-library/downloads

Step3: register the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml before closing your closing your application tag file as shown below

```
<application>
:
:
:

<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.IntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.urbanairship.airmail.END_REGISTER"></action>
<action android:name="com.urbanairship.airmail.ACCEPT_PUSH"></action>
<action android:name="com.urbanairship.airmail.NOTIFY"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Step 4: Login in your Account, Register Your Application in their site. For that Click Apps option in your account.

Step5: After Clicking the Apps the icon, you are able to see Add your Application Option as shown in the following diagram

Step6: Enter your App Name and Click Push Notification Support, then fed your package name. and Click create your App Button, A new Window will give you,Application Key.

Step 7: Create a file called ua.properties under raw folder which is under in res folder, i.e., res/raw/ua.properties file

Step8: Fed the Application Key which you got after App registartion in Urban AirShip and also finger print of your App in ua.properties file as shown below.

> debug=true debug.app_key=j9kRTqaCRR-E0xf-iu2XEA
>   production.app_key=9D:54:23:3F:F3:25:AB:0B:DC:8E:D9:C8:B3:F4:96:F9

Step 9: Create a Application Class as shown Below

> 

```
import com.urbanairship.push.APIDReceiver; import
 com.urbanairship.push.AirMail; import
 com.urbanairship.push.PushReceiver;

 import android.app.Application; import android.content.Intent; import
 android.util.Log;

 public class PushNotification extends Application { public void
 onCreate(){ AirMail am = AirMail.getInstance(); am.acceptPush(this,
 new PushReceiver() { @Override public void onReceive(String message,
 String payload){ Log.d("push", "Got message '" + message +"' and
 payload '" + payload + "'"); }

 @Override public void onClick(String message, String payload){
 Log.d("push", "User clicked the notification, got message and payload:
 "
 + message + ", " + payload); /* In this example, we fire up our MainActivity class when the
 * user clicks the Status Bar Notification. Note that we *must*
 * use the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to start a new
 * activity because this callback is fired from within a
* BroadcastReceiver.
**/ Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); intent.setClass(PushNotification.this,MainActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 PushNotification.this.startActivity(intent); } });

 am.setAPIDReceiver(this, new APIDReceiver() { @Override public void
 onReceive(String apid, boolean valid){ if(valid){ Log.d("push", "Got
 apid: " + apid); } else { Log.d("push", "Application registration
 invalid!"); } }

 @Override public void onAirMailInstallRefusal() {
 Rss_Feed_Grid.register = false; Log.d("push", "AirMail Install
 Refused!"); } }); } }
```

Step 10: Check the following registration code in your Activity

```
 protected static boolean register = true;

 if(register){ AirMail am = AirMail.getInstance(); am.register(this); }
```

Step 11:
Update Your Manifest in order to register your application

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".PushNotification">
```

Step12: Now Click Push Notification and then click feed Button in Urbran Air Ship, then fed url which is to be monitored

That's it..

Refer my blog for more information
http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.sg/p/push-notification-in-android-using.html