# Send data to specific device without GCM

Tags: php, android, remote-control

I'm looking for the best approach to send data(*String*) from **my server** (*PHP*) to one **specific android device**. 
I can check the device if is *online/offline* on my server(with http-post method). But I don't know how to send data to spesific device ***without GCM***. *(I'm not looking for push notification and I'll send message to maximum 100 user.)*

Comment: anyhelp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297246/are-there-any-alternative-to-gcm-google-cloud-messaging-for-custom-android-bui

Comment: GCM/Firebase silent push notifications do exactly what you want, and they ensure  that the device's battery saving states are used optimally. I use websockets when i need lots of realtime communication between device and backend, but an additional nodejs server was needed to set this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using GCM, you have several options:

- **app polls server for updates, at a specified interval**. It may impact device's battery life and network usage.
- **app opens TCP connection to the server** which is then used by server to send updates to app. I'm pretty sure it's not something you want to do in PHP, though.
- **server sends an SMS to the device** (assuming it's a phone) and app intercepts it. This would require your server to know the phone number of the recipient and implies using some SMS API (usually paid).
- **app (WebView or web app) uses WebSockets** to connect to server
- **use push service different than GCM** (i.e. Urban Airship)

From all of those I would look into polling first. It's often considere somewhat a bad practice, but it's not necessarily the case. Have a look at this [AT&T blog post](http://networkingexchangeblog.att.com/enterprise-business/push-or-poll-how-email-setup-can-save-your-battery-life/) for some measurements.

Comment: I choosed the GCM, I'm grateful for your detailed answer.

Comment: @Jessica, yeah, I would probably choose it too. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

An other solutions is to use an [MQTT](https://mqtt.org/) .

1. Install MQTT in your server and create your queue.
2. Write to the queue in PHP with one of the PHP libraries : https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/libraries
3. In Android receive the message with  http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

The communication is asynchronous and all work inside your LAN without external public service (like GCM).

I hope this can be helpful.